# Showing that a sum diverges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

> Suppose that $a_{j} \geq 0$ and that $\sum a_{j}$ diverges. Prove that $\sum\frac{a_{j}}{1+a{j}}$ diverges.

The hint that is given is show that it if it converges $a_{j} \rightarrow 0$. I don't understand why that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you prove this result under the additional hypothesis that $a_j\leqslant1$ for every $j$?

Answer (score 3):

If it converges, then $a_j\to 0$. But then for large enough $j$, we have $1+a_j\lt 2$. Then $\sum a_j$ converges by Comparison, since for large enough $j$ we have $a_j\lt 2\frac{a_j}{1+a_j}$.